# Find most meaningful variables on a dataset

Tags: matlab, correlation, data-analysis

Let's say I have a set of variables (vectors, all of them with the same length **N**): **X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6...Xn.** and a time series **Y** (with the same length **N**) that depend on some variables X .

I need an algorithm to determine which of the variables **X** are most correlated with **Y**. i.e I need to discard the least meaningful variables and get the MOST influential variables on **Y**.

Example:

Let's say we want to determine what influences the web traffic of a specific IT site. And we have 5 keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, and keyword5.

Let's say we have the keywords' search volume on Google **(key1= X1,key2= X2,key3=X3,key4=X4,key5=X5)**, and the total web traffic **Y**. I want to determine what keywords from the set above (X1,X2,X3,X4, or X5) are most meaningful to the total web traffic to that website. Which variables I can discard and which ones move the most traffic. (Let's say all these vectors and the time series are normalized and standardized time series that range from 0-100)

Comment: If you think most of the variables have a linear relationship with the output Y you can do a stepwise regression http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/stepwisefit.html to determine what variables to include in your model

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but this general class of problems is known in the machine learning community as *feature selection*.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) describes a number of different methods you could try, some of which are implemented right out-of-the-box in Matlab's Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.  Stepwise linear regression, as @SomeGuy mentioned, is one of them.  Another popular one is the [lasso method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using feature selection svm.

I have done this successfully using Feature Generation Machine. 
Please check this link: http://www.tanmingkui.com/fgm.html